# Is replace row-wise and will overwrite the value within the dict twice?

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have following data set

```
lst = ['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']
lst_rev = list(reversed(lst))
dct = dict(zip(lst, lst_rev))

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a'],
                   'B':lst},
                   dtype='category')
```

Now I want to `replace` the value of column B in df by `dct`

I know I can do

`df.B.map(dct).fillna(df.B)`

to get the expected out put , but when I test with `replace` (which is more straightforward base on my thinking ), I failed

The out put show as below

```
df.B.replace(dct)
Out[132]: 
0    u
1    v
2    w
3    v
4    u
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Which is different from the

```
df.B.map(dct).fillna(df.B)
Out[133]: 
0    y
1    x
2    w
3    v
4    u
Name: B, dtype: object
```

I can think that the reason why this happen, But why ?

```
0    u --> change to y then change to u
1    v --> change to x then change to v
2    w
3    v
4    u
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `replace` keeps applying the dictionary

```
df.B.replace({'u': 'v', 'v': 'w', 'w': 'x', 'x': 'y', 'y': 'Hello'})

0    Hello
1    Hello
2    Hello
3    Hello
4    Hello
Name: B, dtype: object
```

---

With the given `dct` `'u'` -> `'y'` then `'y'` -> `'u'`.

Comment: Is this intended behavior? I couldn't see anything in the docs, or find any issues related to this.

Comment: If that is case if we want to change three value like `a-b b-c c-a` we can only using map right ?

Comment: @user3483203 Not sure tbh.  Wen, yes.

Comment: @piRSquared this is interesting behavior , which mean when we do `replace` , pandas restore the intermediate variable somewhere . :-)

Comment: It must.  Kinda like `f = lambda x: dct.get(x, x); while s != s.map(f): s = s.map(f)`

Comment: I submitted an issue on their github page, hopefully I get a response, perhaps it is intended

Comment: @user3483203 I am not sure about others , I just aware of this behavior ..

Comment: Sir would you mind I unaccepted your answer after two days and open a bounty for this question ?

Answer (score 5):

This behavior is *not* intended, and was recognized as a bug.

[This is the Github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20656) that first identified the behavior, and it was added as a milestone for `pandas 0.24.0`.  I can confirm the replacement works as expected in the current version on Github.

[Here is the PR containing the fix.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/21477)