# Python - Swap values in multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this

```
id  val1   val2
0    A      B
1    B      B
2    A      A
3    A      A
```

And I would like swap values such as:

```
id  val1   val2
0    B      A
1    A      A
2    B      B
3    B      B
```

I need to consider that the df could have other columns that I would like to keep unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

Try `stack`ing, `map`ping, and then `unstack`ing:

```
df[['val1', 'val2']] = (
    df[['val1', 'val2']].stack().map({'B': 'A', 'A': 'B'}).unstack())

df
   id val1 val2
0   0    B    A
1   1    A    A
2   2    B    B
3   3    B    B
```

For a (much) faster solution, use a nested list comprehension.

```
mapping = {'B': 'A', 'A': 'B'}
df[['val1', 'val2']] = [
    [mapping.get(x, x) for x in row] for row in df[['val1', 'val2']].values]

df
   id val1 val2
0   0    B    A
1   1    A    A
2   2    B    B
3   3    B    B
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with a dictionary:

```
d = {'B': 'A', 'A': 'B'}

df = df.applymap(d.get).fillna(df)

print(df)

  id val1 val2
0  0    B    A
1  1    A    A
2  2    B    B
3  3    B    B
```

For performance, in particular memory usage, you may wish to use [categorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html):

```
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
    df[col] = df[col].cat.rename_categories(d)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `factorize` and roll the corresponding values

```
def swaparoo(col):
  i, r = col.factorize()
  return pd.Series(r[(i + 1) % len(r)], col.index)

df[['id']].join(df[['val1', 'val2']].apply(swaparoo))

   id val1 val2
0   0    B    A
1   1    A    A
2   2    B    B
3   3    B    B
```

---

Alternative gymnastics using the same function.  This incorporates the whole dataframe into the factorization.

```
df.set_index('id').stack().pipe(swaparoo).unstack().reset_index()
```

---

#### Examples

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=range(4), val1=[*'ABAA'], val2=[*'BBAA']))

print(
    df,
    df.set_index('id').stack().pipe(swaparoo).unstack().reset_index(),
    sep='\n\n'
)

   id val1 val2
0   0    A    B
1   1    B    B
2   2    A    A
3   3    A    A

   id val1 val2
0   0    B    A
1   1    A    A
2   2    B    B
3   3    B    B
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=range(4), val1=[*'AAAA'], val2=[*'BBBB']))

print(
    df,
    df.set_index('id').stack().pipe(swaparoo).unstack().reset_index(),
    sep='\n\n'
)

   id val1 val2
0   0    A    B
1   1    A    B
2   2    A    B
3   3    A    B

   id val1 val2
0   0    B    A
1   1    B    A
2   2    B    A
3   3    B    A
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=range(4), val1=[*'AAAA'], val2=[*'BBBB'], val3=[*'CCCC']))

print(
    df,
    df.set_index('id').stack().pipe(swaparoo).unstack().reset_index(),
    sep='\n\n'
)

   id val1 val2 val3
0   0    A    B    C
1   1    A    B    C
2   2    A    B    C
3   3    A    B    C

   id val1 val2 val3
0   0    B    C    A
1   1    B    C    A
2   2    B    C    A
3   3    B    C    A
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=range(4), val1=[*'ABCD'], val2=[*'BCDA'], val3=[*'CDAB']))

print(
    df,
    df.set_index('id').stack().pipe(swaparoo).unstack().reset_index(),
    sep='\n\n'
)

   id val1 val2 val3
0   0    A    B    C
1   1    B    C    D
2   2    C    D    A
3   3    D    A    B

   id val1 val2 val3
0   0    B    C    D
1   1    C    D    A
2   2    D    A    B
3   3    A    B    C
```

Comment: this remind me this question ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52506862/is-replace-row-wise-and-will-overwrite-the-value-within-the-dict-twice

Comment: I thought of the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

You can swap two values efficiently using `numpy.where`.  However, if there are *more* than two values, this method stops working.

```
a = df[['val1', 'val2']].values
df[['val1', 'val2']] = np.where(a=='A', 'B', 'A')
```

```
   id val1 val2
0   0    B    A
1   1    A    A
2   2    B    B
3   3    B    B
```

---

To adapt this keep other values the same, you can use `np.select`:

```
c1 = a=='A'
c2 = a=='B'
np.select([c1, c2], ['B', 'A'], a)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `replace` : why we need a C here , check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52506862/is-replace-row-wise-and-will-overwrite-the-value-within-the-dict-twice)

```
df[['val1','val2']].replace({'A':'C','B':'A','C':'B'})
Out[263]: 
  val1 val2
0    B    A
1    A    A
2    B    B
3    B    B
```

Comment: This is a funny way to go about it :). I once [looked into](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49259581/9209546) that awful `replace` function... so needlessly complex the mind boggles. The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) have this "gem": `You are encouraged to experiment and play with this method to gain intuition about how it works.`

Comment: @jpp yep ,I am still waiting for them to fix the bug /;-(